# CSS3 background color + image

Tags: css, background, opacity, transparent

I have a background image and want to add a transparent fill color on top of that. I use modern browsers like Firefox and Google Chrome.

**This code works (but does not solve the problem)**

```
background: url('bkg.jpg'), rgba(0,0,0, .5);
```

**This code don't work (but should solve my problem)**

```
background: rgba(0,0,0, .5), url('bkg.jpg');
```

Why? Solution?

Comment: you want to make a transparent fill color or do you want the image to be transparent?

Comment: The background image is not going to be transparent. The color on top should be. Then the background "glows" through the color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background says:

> Note: The background-color can only be defined on the last background,
>   as there is only one background color for the whole element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering says:

> The background color, if present, is painted below all of the other
>   layers.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-color says:

> This property sets the background color of an element. The color is
>   drawn behind any background images.

Maybe you could use the `:before/:after` pseudoelements instead with absolute positioning.

http://jsfiddle.net/3mNkZ/3/

```
div {
    background: rgba(0,255,0, .5);
    width: 200px; height: 200px;
    border: 10px solid red;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: white;
}

div:before {
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/200/150');
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
​
```

Comment: Does not work for me. Background color is going behind background image.

Comment: Ended up creating 2 child divs - one for background image and one for background color as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9730776/828062.

Comment: Interesting, what browser were you using?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a div that is the same size as the window to get the effect.
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2SwG/) and the code below.

```
html{
    background: url('http://tribulant.net/lightbox/files/2010/08/image-2.jpg');
}
.color {
    background-color: rgb(100,0,0); 
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

​